# Как извлечь кусок текста с помощью регулярки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Есть вот такой текст

```html
<div class="company_view_rating_text">
                                    2 из 1114                               </div>
```

Мне нужно извлечь из него цифру "2". Я использую вот такую функцию с регуляркой

```php
preg_match_all('#<div class="company_view_rating_text">$(.+?).+?из.+?</div>#', $site, $res);
```

Но ничего не получается. Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ответы на этот вопрос будут полезны только автору, расширению базы знаний они нисколько не помогают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заработал ваш шаблон, нужно его немного изменить:

1. Включить модификатор `m` - [PCRE_MULTILINE](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), чтобы начал срабатывать якорь конца строки `$`
2. Добавить в шаблон маску для пропуска произвольного кол-ва пробельных символов сразу после перевода строки: `\s*`
3. Обернуть группу, которая принимает значение номера страницы, якорями границы слова `\b`: `\b(.+?)\b`

```
preg_match_all(
    '#<div class="company_view_rating_text">$\s*\b(.+?)\b.+?из.+?</div>#m',
    $site,
    $res
);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hVFtvB/3)

===

**Обновлен в ответ на комментарий автора вопроса**

Чтобы сделать шаблон более устойчивым к форматированию входных данных, я бы предпочел использовать такой шаблон:

```
preg_match_all(
    '#<div class="company_view_rating_text">\s*(\d+)\s+из.+?</div>#s',
    $site,
    $res
);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hVFtvB/4)

Comment: Я бы не стал ставить якорь конца строки, что будет, если в следующий раз данные придут в одну строку

Comment: когда в php скрипте запускаю ваш код, мне результатом выводится пустой массив ```$site = '<div class="company_view_rating_text">
                                    2 из 1114                               </div>';
preg_match_all('#<div class="company_view_rating_text">$\s*\b(.+?)\b.+?из.+?</div>#m', $site, $res);``` http://prntscr.com/og3a10

Comment: @ВладимирАфанасьев я дополнил свой ответ

Comment: спасибо, решение работает замечательно